# Symmetric Group $S_n$ is generated by transpositions.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I have to proof, that a symmetric group $S_n$, with $n \geq 2$ with support $\{a_1, a_2, ... , a_p\}$ such that $σ(a_k)= a_k+1$ (when $k < p$) and $σ(a_p)=a_1$, is generated by transposition $(1,2)$ and the cycle $σ=(1,2,...,n)$.

I started by verifying that $σ(1)(1,2)σ(2) = (2,3)$. 
Then by iteration I show that the next transposition $(3,4) = σ(1)(2,3) σ(2)...$ Iterating until transposition $(n,1)$. 
After this how can I then proof that $S_n$ is generated by this transposition?

Thanks!

Comment: See also: [$(12)$ and $(123\dots n)$ are generators of $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520615) and some of the [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/520615).