# Does the set of automorphisms of the integers modulo n have the same number of elements as the symmetric group of order n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

As stated in the question header, does the set of automorphisms of the ring of integers modulo n have the same number of elements as the symmetric group of order n?

I tried creating the permutation (0,1) using the automorphisms in the ring $Z_n$, but couldn't do it successfully. I found that the group of automorphisms is restricted. Which is to say, no combination of multiplications and additions in $Z_n$ could produce (0,1), which is a necessity to generate all of $S_n$. (0,1,..,n-1) is of course present with +1. ([$(12)$ and $(123\dots n)$ are generators of $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520615/12-and-123-dots-n-are-generators-of-s-n)).

Although I think I've found an answer, how can I prove this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Nope. The automorphism group of of the ring of integers modulo n is the trivial group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every ring $R$ and every automorphism $f : R \to R$, we have $f(0)=0$. This follows from two facts: the additive identity of a ring is unique; and $f(0)$ is an additive identity of $R$.

So that already tells you that if $n$ is the number of elements of a finite ring $R$ then the number of automorphisms is $\le (n-1)!$ which, of course, is strictly less than $n!$.